# Input python nested loop

Tags: python, loops, nested

```
line = int(input("How many items are in the chart?: "))
 for i in range(line + 1):
    for j in range(line):  
        number = int(input("How much of this specific item?: "))
        _star = "*"
    print(_star * number)
    break
```

With this code I am trying to take user input for each line to print the specific amount of items on each line. However the code only takes the last input for the specific item and prints that one line. What am I overlooking to print each line for the specified input?

Comment: Indentation? Also why do you `break`?

Comment: Indeed: `print` must be one level deeper, and `break` is not needed at all.

Comment: If i do not break there it would be infinite. Carcigenicate that makes sense, ill play around with fixing that. Thank you.

Comment: It won't be infinite if you don't break there. It will be ((line + 1) * line) iterations

Comment: I guess you want to print as many stars as the number of a specific item? At least that is what your code would do if the print was indented into the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but this code might work. Your problem is that you're not printing within the inner for loop. 
Also that break will immediately exit the loop so you'll only get a single iteration of the outer loop.

```
line = int(input("How many items are in the chart?: "))
for i in range(line + 1):
    for j in range(line):
        number = int(input("How much of this specific item?: "))
        _star = "*"
        print(_star * number)
```

Again I'm not totally sure if this is what you want because I don't completely understand your question, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.

If you just want to see the "chart" of printed stars this will give you the result that you want.

```
line = int(input("How many items are in the chart?: "))
stars = []
for i in range(line + 1):
    number = int(input("How much of this specific item?: "))
    stars.append(number)

for i in stars:
    print '*' * i
```

**Output:**
How many items are in the chart?: 4

How much of this specific item?: 1

How much of this specific item?: 2

How much of this specific item?: 3

How much of this specific item?: 2

How much of this specific item?: 1

*

**

***

**

*

Happy Coding!

Comment: I apologize for the vague question. I'll explain in more detail. After the user inputs all of his items in the variable number, I want the code to print one whole chart that contain * for each specific item rather than printing the amount of * and then asking again how many items there are for the row. Does this make a little more sense?

Comment: so the variable line is the number of columns and the variable number is the number of stars per row?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print each items details entered by user input. If I understand what you were trying to do correctly, then this should do the job.

```
line = int(input("How many items are in the chart?: "))
for i in range(line):
    number = int(input("How much of this specific item?: "))
    _star = "*"
    print(_star * number)
```